# Is there an alternative to Bouncer- Temporary app permissions?

Tags: applications, privacy, open-source

I'm really paranoid about my privacy idk why. Recently I installed Whatsapp Aero which is super cool but unfortunately its developer is expert in making spyware apps too. I found this [Bouncer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samruston.permission&hl=en_IN&gl=US) which provides permissions temporarily. But this app is paid and not open source again. I tried shelter app to isolate it but due to the dual app feature in my phone i can't a add work profile. Can anyone suggest me how can i monitor what the app does in background OR make an script which grants and revokes permissions through adb OR any alternative to Bouncer? I'm gonna buy the bounce app if i'm outta options. The developer deserves it :)

P.S.  My device is not rooted.

Comment: Hi, take note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not putting any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: @AndrewT. Oh okay

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using  [Android Mobile Device Hardening](https://github.com/SecTheTech/AMDH) which:

- list installed apps and their dangerous permissions
- revoke dangerous permissions for all Apps
- list applications that are device admin

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As it's mentioned it lists all the permissions and i will have to manually revoke it. I use whatsapp very often and can't always grant and revoke permissions it so tedious. So it's potentially useless for me.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the benefits are avaialble with a modified device (Custom ROM Flashed). Your phone is faster and better without Google Apps. Root acceess gives you the added benefits of apps like [App Ops](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rikka.appops) and [Storage Isolation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=moe.shizuku.redirectstorage). These are precisely the apps that you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah that's true indeed but it's a new phone and i can't take the risk of bricking it.