# Is there a way to give permissions temporarily?

Tags: privacy

Is there a way to take away permissions when i leave an app? i dont have root and also no intention to root. is it possible to do this with adb or something??

Comment: As far as I remember this is a new feature of Android 11 e.g. for location permission. Google calls this [One-time permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already asked this question [Is there an alternative to Bouncer- Temporary app permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230632/is-there-an-alternative-to-bouncer-temporary-app-permissions)

I found a temporary solution.. using automate app. You can use its interact block to automate the steps real easy. But it only works when the element is visible. That means we will have to scroll manually. Rest all is easy!